# Find the position of letter i in a list of words

Tags: string-manipulation

I want to find the position of letter i in each word of a text. Take their positions and then sum them up. Example, in simplicity, the score will be 2+6+8=16. In this way, I calculate the score for all words and then sum the scores.

I wrote the following codes till now, but unable to combine them.

```
Data = "Simplicity and Importance are classic and ironic"
TextWords[Data]
Transpose[StringPosition[ToString[Data], "I"]][[1]]
Transpose[StringPosition[ToString[Data], "i"]][[1]]
```

Please help

Comment: Maybe start with `Position[Characters[Data], "i" | "I"]` ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is ambiguous. **(1)** upper/lower case **(2)** Whether this count gets reset after every word. Furthermore, there has been no acceptance/feedback for an extended period of time.

Answer (score 2):

`Transpose[StringPosition[Data, "i", IgnoreCase -> True]][[1]]`

Answer (score 1):

You may use `StringPosition` and `StringSplit` for this, e.g.

```
score[string_] := Total[
  (First /@ StringPosition[#, "i"])& /@ StringSplit[string],
  Infinity
]
```

defines a `score` function that does what you asked for. For example:

```
score["Simplicity"]
(* 16 *)

score["Simplicity and Importance are classic and ironic"]
(* 28 *)
```

You may use `ToLowerCase` if you wish to count capital "I" as well.